# Solidity : After passing it to "true", my bool doesn't pass to false... why?

Tags: visual-studio, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm starting learning Solidity. I'm using *Visual Studio Code* with *Remix* IDE extension.

I already have a little problem

I wrote this simple contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract test2 {

 bool myBool;

 function getBool() public view returns(bool){
    return myBool;
 }

 function setBool(bool _bool) public {
    myBool = _bool;
 }
```

I compiled it and deploy it in testnet Blockchain.

After using `getBool()`, i get a **false**. Nothing to report here...

Then I set the value **true** to `myBool` with `setBool()`. I get a **true** after using `getBool()`. Everything is okay here.

But, when i want to set **false** to `myBool` with `setBool()`, I still obtain a **true** with `getBool()`. I don't understand how and why?

Thank you for your help.
(Sorry for my english if i made some mistakes)

Comment: I tested your code and it is working correctly

Comment: That's really weird... Did you test it in remix.ethereum.org or with VS Code and the extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not enough reputation to just comment so it will be an anwer. Your code is correct but there are may be some tricky issues.

1. The first "false" is the default value as bool is "value type". Read the first paragraph from [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#scoping-and-declarations).
2. I would reccomend you use remix ide itself (online version for example). I guess different ide extensions can not be fully trusted.
3. You may merely had not waited for transaction to be confirmed so you read old value.